# How do i add up all the numbers from 1 to the number given by the user

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to complete an exercise in which i can get an input from the user and add up all the numbers from 1 to that number, and display the total.

Can somebody tell me how do i add up all the numbers from 1 to the number given by the user..

This exercise is supposed to be done with a for loop

***here is my code:-***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AddValsInLoop1WF {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

        int guess;

        System.out.print("Number: ");
        guess = key.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= guess; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared `s`? Where should you accumulate the sum?

Comment: Shouldn't you do your own homework?

Comment: Add up all the numbers? Which numbers? Natural, rational, irrational?

Comment: I suggest getting the number from the user, then adding up all the numbers from 1 to that number, then follow that up by displaying the result to the user. Pasting an arbitrary bit of code then asking others to do your homework for you does not count as "effort".

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= guess; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

`sum` is your accumulator.

Comment: +1 for being helpful, -1 for [feeding vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), which only attracts more.

Comment: @JasonC Everyone's got to start somewhere.  Some need a bigger push than others.  I forgive him, due to having a 4 day old account.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= guess; i++) {
        count += i;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + count);
```